# What do you do with the items that are made on Imperial levels in Tiny Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

You 'collect' them when done and have an inventory of them.  Can they be sold?

Answer (score 1):

You use them to finish the imperial quests.  Tap on the hologram of Darth Vader to see these quests.  When you complete the quests, you will gain credits.